# Delete a record in MySql database by clicking a dynamically generated button in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to programming and hoping someone will help me with my problem. I'm developing an e-commerce application and looking to add buttons to a dynamically generated list of items in the cart. I used a loop statement to go through each row of the table and show the results but I don't know how to remove a record once the user clicks a button. Here is the code for the cart. Please advise. [end result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTZ60.png)

```
 private void CartPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        DB db = new DB();

       
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `Product_Info` WHERE `Cart_Number` = @cart", db.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@cart", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Global.cart;
        
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        int rowcount = table.Rows.Count;

        if (rowcount > 0)
        {
            
            //MessageBox.Show("You have products");
            int Left = 45;
            int Top = 100;
            int rownumb = 0;
           
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                
                Label ProdName_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(ProdName_label);
                Label Name_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(Name_label);

                Label ProdNo_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(ProdNo_label);
                Label No_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(No_label);

                Label ProdQty_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(ProdQty_label);
                Label Qty_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(Qty_label);

                Label ProdPrice_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(ProdPrice_label);
                Label Price_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(Price_label);

                Label PrdSub_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(PrdSub_label);
                Label Sub_label = new Label();
                this.Controls.Add(Sub_label);

                Button Remove_button = new Button();
                this.Controls.Add(Remove_button);

                Panel Product_panel = new Panel();
                this.Controls.Add(Product_panel);

                Product_panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(Remove_button);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(PrdSub_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(Sub_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(ProdNo_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(No_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(ProdQty_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(Qty_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(ProdPrice_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(Price_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(ProdName_label);
                Product_panel.Controls.Add(Name_label);
                Product_panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Left, Top);
                Product_panel.Name = "Product_panel";
                Product_panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
                Product_panel.TabIndex = 2;
                
                
                // 
                // ProdName_label
                // 

                ProdName_label.AutoSize = true;
                ProdName_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 25);
                ProdName_label.Name = "ProdName_label";
                ProdName_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 32);
                ProdName_label.TabIndex = 3;
                ProdName_label.Text = "Product Name:";


                Name_label.AutoSize = true;
                Name_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 25);
                Name_label.Name = "Name_label";
                Name_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 32);
                Name_label.TabIndex = 3;
                Name_label.Text = table.Rows[rownumb]["Prod_Name"].ToString();

                //// 
                //// ProdNo_label
                //// 
                ProdNo_label.AutoSize = true;
                ProdNo_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 45);
                ProdNo_label.Name = "ProdNo_label";
                ProdNo_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 32);
                ProdNo_label.TabIndex = 4;
                ProdNo_label.Text = "Product Number:";

                No_label.AutoSize = true;
                No_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 45);
                No_label.Name = "No_label";
                No_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 32);
                No_label.TabIndex = 4;
                No_label.Text = "1";
                No_label.Text = table.Rows[rownumb]["Prod_Number"].ToString();
              




                // 
                // ProdPrice_label
                // 
                ProdPrice_label.AutoSize = true;
                ProdPrice_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 65);
                ProdPrice_label.Name = "ProdPrice_label";
                ProdPrice_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 32);
                ProdPrice_label.TabIndex = 4;
                ProdPrice_label.Text = "Price:";

                Price_label.AutoSize = true;
                Price_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 65);
                Price_label.Name = "Price_label";
                Price_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 32);
                Price_label.TabIndex = 4;
                Price_label.Text = table.Rows[rownumb]["Prod_Price"].ToString();

                //// 
                //// ProdQty_label
                //// 
                ProdQty_label.AutoSize = true;
                ProdQty_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 85);
                ProdQty_label.Name = "ProdQty_label";
                ProdQty_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(173, 32);
                ProdQty_label.TabIndex = 4;
                ProdQty_label.Text = "Product Q-ty:";

                Qty_label.AutoSize = true;
                Qty_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 85);
                Qty_label.Name = "ProdQty_label";
                Qty_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(173, 32);
                Qty_label.TabIndex = 4;
                Qty_label.Text = table.Rows[rownumb]["Prod_Qty"].ToString();

                //// 
                //// PrdSub_label
                //// 
                PrdSub_label.AutoSize = true;
                PrdSub_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 105);
                PrdSub_label.Name = "PrdSub_label";
                PrdSub_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(226, 32);
                PrdSub_label.TabIndex = 5;
                PrdSub_label.Text = "Product Subtotal:";

                Sub_label.AutoSize = true;
                Sub_label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 105);
                Sub_label.Name = "Sub_label";
                Sub_label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(226, 32);
                Sub_label.TabIndex = 5;
                Sub_label.Text = table.Rows[rownumb]["Prod_Subtotal"].ToString();
     



                //// 
                //// Remove_button
                //// 
                Remove_button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                Remove_button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 150);
                Remove_button.Name = "Remove_button" + Convert.ToString(rownumb);
                Remove_button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 34);
                Remove_button.TabIndex = 3;
                Remove_button.Text = "Remove";
                Remove_button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
                Remove_button.Click += new System.EventHandler(Remove_button_Click);
              


                Top += 220;
                rownumb += 1;
            }

           

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have any products in your cart");
        }

 

    }


    private void Remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Remove", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        
    }
```

Comment: Split the problem into parts: can you generate those buttons? Can you attach a handler to those buttons? Can you make that handler know which button was clicked (tip: the sender is that button)? Can you then use that info to execute a delete command?

Comment: For each row in the table a button is generated.  So each record has a button but the buttons have the same name so I can delete all records but not a specific record. I don't know how to make it work so the app "knows" that I clicked a button that corresponds to product #100 for example. I need to use a product number to delete the record from the cart.

Comment: IIRC the Button has a Tag property that you can set to (for instance) a record number

Comment: So how can I then refer to the tag for the click event? Thank you for the advise.

Comment: In your remove_button_click, cast "sender" to Button, then you can access its .Tag

Comment: I don't understand. Would you be able to provide a code? Thank you

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question? [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - that helps future readers with a similar problem to identify helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

Your issue apparently is "how do I know *which* button was clicked?".

You already know how to create a button, add it to the form and attach a click-handler:

```
   Button Remove_button = new Button();
   this.Controls.Add(Remove_button);

   Remove_button.Name = "Remove_button" + Convert.ToString(rownumb);
   Remove_button.Click += new System.EventHandler(Remove_button_Click);
```

To know which button was clicked, you can set its [`.Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) property:

```
   Remove_button.Tag = Convert.ToString(rownumb); // or whatever the primary key for this row is
```

Next, in the click handler, you need to read that property.
Fortunately, when the button calls the handler, it uses (a reference to) itself as the `sender` parameter.
So when you cast that `sender` to a `Button`, you get the real button that originated the command and you can access all its properties, such as `.Tag`:

```
    private void Remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
        string rownumb = clickedButton.Tag;

        DialogResult selection = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove item #" + rownumb + "?",
              "Remove", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        // TODO execute a DELETE command for this row when the user clicked OK
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I don't fully understand how the Remove_button.Tag got copied to the rownumb string?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You create different button(as you should), so each has its own Tag value. When calling the Click handler, the button passes itself as "sender". So in the handler you can access the button that issued the event and read its Tag

Comment: Now I understand. So basically I can access anything - Name, Text etc. right?

Comment: Correct, you have the exact button that you previously added to the page